# Node.JS - Mongoose won't save data to MongoDB and Object not getting information correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So firstly, I checked the relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256707/mongoose-doesnt-save-data-to-the-mongodb) but since I'm not using the same  middleware, I don't think it helped me. I have a regular form and while it successfully goes through req.body and I can print all the form values. However the problems are when I try to create a new object because when I print it, it doesn't have the correct fields that I assigned it...? And secondly, when I try to save it, it doesn't show up in the Db when I check via Terminal. I have successfully run Mongod and am connected to the correct Db and collection so I'm confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Here is the relevant code**

*App.js*:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db = require('./db.js');
var path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var handlebars = require('hbs');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var museumObj = mongoose.model('MuseumObject');

//For Images
var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');
//Saves to memory storage 
var upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage({}) });

//Port setting
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/AdvancedSearch', function(req, res) {
    res.render('AdvancedSearch');
});

app.get('/AskUs', function(req, res) {
    res.render('AskUs');
});

app.get('/Themes', function(req, res) {
    res.render('Themes');
});

app.get('/AddObj',  function(req, res) {
    res.render('AddObj');
});

app.post('/AddObj',upload.single('pic'),function(req,res){
    console.log("here is the req.body");
    console.log(req.body);
    var base64 = req.file.buffer.toString('base64');

    var dim='';
    if(req.body.length && req.body.width && req.body.height){
        dim = req.body.req.body.length +" x "+req.body.width+" x "+req.body.height
    }

    var newObj = new museumObj({
        accessionNum: req.body.accession,
        maker: req.body.maker,
        manufacturer: req.body.manufacturer,
        title: req.body.title,
        date: req.body.date,
        medium: req.body.medium,
        dimesions: dim,
        marks: req.body.marks,
        description: req.body.description,
        pic: base64,
    });
    console.log('here is the new object before calling the save function');
    console.log(newObj);
    newObj.save(function(err,item, count){
        if (err){
            console.log("there is an error");
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log('here is the "successfully" saved item');
            console.log(item);
            //res.redirect('/');
        }
    });

});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

*Db.js*:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var URLSlugs = require('mongoose-url-slugs');


var MuseumObject = new mongoose.Schema({
  accessionNum: String,
  maker: {String, default: ''},
  manufacturer: {String, default: ''},
  title: String,  
  date: {String, default: ''},
  medium: {String, default: ''}, 
  dimensions: {String, default: ''},
  marks: {String, default: ''},
  description: {String, default: ''},
  pic: {String, default: ''}
});


MuseumObject.plugin(URLSlugs('title'));
mongoose.model('MuseumObject', MuseumObject);

// is the environment variable, NODE_ENV, set to PRODUCTION? 
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'PRODUCTION') {
  console.log("in production");
 // if we're in PRODUCTION mode, then read the configration from a file
 // use blocking file io to do this...
 var fs = require('fs');
 var path = require('path');
 var fn = path.join(__dirname, 'config.json');
 var data = fs.readFileSync(fn);

 // our configuration file will be in json, so parse it and set the
 // conenction string appropriately!
 var conf = JSON.parse(data);
 var dbconf = conf.dbconf;
} 
else {
 // if we're not in PRODUCTION mode, then use
 dbconf = 'mongodb://localhost/BKMuseum';
}

mongoose.connect(dbconf);
```

*HTML File*:

```
<h1>Add an Object to the Collection<h1>

<h3>

 <form method="POST" action="AddObj" id="AddObj" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        *Accession #:  <input type="text" name = "accession" value ="" required>
        <BR>
        Maker/Designer/Artist: <input type="text" name = "maker" value ="">
        <BR>
        Manufacturer: <input type="text" name = "manufacturer" value ="" >
        <BR>
        *Title: <input type="text" name = "title" value ="" required >
        <BR>
        {{!-- Dates can be in string format: ca. 1930 vs. 1932-1934--}}
        *Date : <input type="text" name="date" value="" required>
        <BR>
        *Medium: <input type="text" name="medium" value="" required>
        <BR>
        <div>
            Dimensions:
            <blockquote>
                <input type="number" name="length" form="AddObj"> X <input type="number" name="width" form="AddObj"> X <input type="number" name="height" form="AddObj">
            </blockquote>
        </div> 
        Marks: <input type="text" name="marks" value="">
        <div> Description
                <BR>
                <textarea name="description" form="AddObj" cols='50' style="resize:none; font-size:16px;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Image Upload
            <BR>
            <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" form="AddObj" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" form="AddObj">
    </form>

</3>
    <p>
        <a href="/">Go Back to Research Center's Home Page </a href>
    </p>
```

**Here is the relevant outputs** 

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSYsV.png)
- *Mongo console output:*

> use BKMuseum
>   switched to db BKMuseum
>   db.BKMuseum.count()
>   0
>   db.BKMuseum.find({})

- [*Form Input*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4hRy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add second parameter which is your collection name

```
 var MuseumObject = new mongoose.Schema({
      accessionNum: String,
      maker: {String, default: ''},
      manufacturer: {String, default: ''},
      title: String,  
      date: {String, default: ''},
      medium: {String, default: ''}, 
      dimensions: {String, default: ''},
      marks: {String, default: ''},
      description: {String, default: ''},
      pic: {String, default: ''}
    },
    {collection:"your_collection_name"});
```

Comment: I think once he has registered a model in another file. He can access it by `var museumObj = mongoose.model('MuseumObject');`, right?

Comment: @Tolsee yes,but he is not using that one while creating modal in app.js.He created model in Db.js but not exporting it.So,either export that one or create new one in app.js as both modal object having differant scope and refarance

Comment: I don't think that is the case, he has registered a model which I think is then accessed from mongoose if you want to use a single connection.

Comment: @Tolsee  please go throgh http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html and please provide short script which wrong to this docs

Comment: I think module.export statement is missing in model.js

Comment: Thanks for your help!I'm a little confused since I do use in app.js : var db = require('./db.js');